# States declare own right side menu while left menu is always present

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My left side menu needs to persists across all states, but each state can optionally have a right side menu with whatever content that state chooses. For now, I've implemented this by making the content of the left side menu a directive of it's own that each state has to include. It's not very DRY and the left side menu is reloaded across states. It works, but it's not ideal.

The following approach is intuitive, but doesn't work because the right side-menu is nested in the ion-nav-view instead of being a direct child of ion-side-menus.

```
ion-side-menus
  ion-side-menu-content
    ion-nav-view // states want to include their own right side menu
  ion-side-menu(side="left")
    main-nav

// some-state.jade
some-directive
ion-side-menu(side="right") // side menu is broken because it's nested
```

If the right side menu is a direct child of ion-nav-view, is there a way for a state to decide what content is in it?

```
ion-side-menus
  ion-side-menu-content
    ion-nav-view
  ion-side-menu(side="right")
    // side menu content here according to current state...
  ion-side-menu(side="left")
    main-nav
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ionic`, but it seems to be using `ui.router`. With `ui.router` you should be able to define different named views and define what they are for each state. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: @NewDev I think you're right that it could let each state declare a named view that would go into the right menu.. then I'd just have to pick a way of removing the right menu when a state doesn't want it. Maybe a slightly hacky ng-if would be ok.

Comment: I would think that not having that named view for a state would remove it. Is that not what happens?

Comment: @NewDev The structure (nesting) of the side menus has to be preserved as is in my last code sample. There would just be a ui-view where that comment is, and it would come and go according to the state, but the side-menu would still be there. It would be nice if I could just nest the side-menu in a ui-view, but not being able to is exactly the problem. I could have states that need it set a property on $rootScope and then check that property like `ng-if="rightMenu"`.

Comment: I don't think I fully follow, to be honest. Is `<ion-nav-view>` where the states render their default view? What is `<ion-side-menu>`? You say "right side menu is nested in the ion-nav-view" but I don't see how in your HTML (and if you don't mind converting to normal HTML from jade, it would help - not everyone is familiar with jade)

Comment: @NewDev Anyone that can figure this out should surely be able to identify the structure without knowing jade =D. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/ I was saying that IF you could nest the side menu in another element, I could just put the right menu in the template of states that need it, but that breaks it. It seems to need to be a direct child of `ion-side-menus`. `ion-nav-view` is a just an extended `ui-view`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, I'm not fully understanding the crux of the question - and if so, I will delete this answer. But, as it seems to me, the approach that you find intuitive is actually counter-intuitive.

The intuitive approach in my mind (which coincides with how ui.router uses named views) is to define the structure of the app first, then define the views that each state would populate.

I am not familiar with ionic, so here's a conceptual example without it:

```
<div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="left">
      left menu: same content for entire app
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      right menu
      <div ui-view="rightside">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- main content -->
  <div class="content" ui-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, each state can populate the `"rightside"` view:

```
.state("stateA", {
  views: {
    "": {
      template: "content of stateA"
    },
    "rightside": {
      template: "menu of stateA"
    }
  }
})
.state("stateB", {
  abstract: true,
  template: "<div ui-view></div>"
})
.state("stateB.B1", {
  views: {
    "": {
      template: "content of stateB.B1"
    },
    "rightside@": {
      template: "menu of stateB.B1"
    }
  }
})
```

Both `stateA` and `stateB.B1` would populate the `"rightside"` view when they load.

Comment: Sure, I'm with you on this part. This does still leave the empty side menu in existence, so you can drag the view over and access it. As I said, an ng-if can take care of that. It's not ideal, but loads better than my current implementation.

Comment: @m59, then why can't you make the `"rightside"` view (in my example) to contain the right menu? In other words, when `"rightside"` doesn't render because it is not defined, then not only would the menu be empty - the menu would (should) be absent.

Comment: That's the part you're missing. The `ion-side-menu` directive has to be a direct child of the `ion-side-menus` directive. You can't put it inside of another element and that makes it awkward to work with, which is the reason for my post.

Comment: @m59, how do you figure that it has to be a direct child?

Comment: Heh, you have a point! I thought I tried it nested any kind of way, but I bet I only tried it nested inside of `ion-side-menu-content` and got to thinking incorrectly from there. Perhaps you're right on. I'll give it a go.

Comment: It's "working" here. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpVbMp I had to change `ion-nav-view` to `ui-view` because the side menus disappear altogether on navigation.. I'll have to figure that out next.

Comment: aaaaannnd, it isn't. If you remove the side menu state from the other view, it keeps an empty side menu from the previous view. Great.

Comment: @m59, I tried the same... and it seems that that is how `ion-side-menu` works - it either register itself with `ion-side-menus` or it doesn't. Using `ng-if` won't help either. So, in other words, it seems that you can either have a right side or not - it is not a switchable (except to turn on) property of `ion-side-menus` - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwKLWO